# Flutter - How to build an IPA file without having an apple paid developer account?

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

Is it possible to build an IPA file without having an active apple developer account? I want to make the IPA for a physical device for testing purposes, but I don't have an active developer account right now!

Comment: Quick answer: no. You need to code sign the app and for that you need a developer account.

Comment: But you can create a free developer account and sign the app using it. You will be able to run the app on your device. You will not be able to distribute it to external testers, or on the store.